How can I obtain the actual value instead of displayed value in Excel?
I have a cell A1 containing a date ex. "26/06/2024". This cell is formatted to display only the day value "26" using Format Cells menu.
How do I get the actual value (i.e. 26/06/2024) of A1 cell in another cell?
I used = VALUE(A1). But not worked.
Any idea?

Use TEXT() function like-
=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")

Or just use =A1 then format the cell as dd/mm/yyyy.
